# Which crop is this?

Tags: agriculture

Can anyone tell me which crop is this. Clicked in France in Aug!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [cannabis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis).

Mature cannabis plants are are tall & "skinny", like the ones in the picture. Also, the density of plants, per unit area of land, suggests it's a plantation crop, quite possibly for illicit purposes.

Comment: That's not exactly how it's grown for "illicit" purposes. That looks more like a crop plant for fiber, etc.

Comment: Apparently France is the largest EU hemp producer. The EU fiber production dwarfs flower production 85,000 tons to 240 tons in 2013.